# Can't spark-submit to analytics node on DataStax Enterprise

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise, spark-submit

I have a 6 node cluster, one of those is spark enabled.

I also have a spark job that I would like to submit to the cluster / that node, so I enter the following command

```sh
spark-submit --class VDQConsumer --master spark://node-public-ip:7077 target/scala-2.10/vdq-consumer-assembly-1.0.jar
```

it launches the spark ui on that node, but eventually gets here:

```
15/05/14 14:19:55 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/Users/cwheeler/dev/git/vdq-consumer/target/scala-2.10/vdq-consumer-assembly-1.0.jar at http://node-ip:54898/jars/vdq-consumer-assembly-1.0.jar with timestamp 1431627595602
15/05/14 14:19:55 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@node-ip:7077/user/Master...
15/05/14 14:19:55 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@node-ip:7077] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
15/05/14 14:20:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@node-ip:7077/user/Master...
15/05/14 14:20:35 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@node-ip:7077/user/Master...
15/05/14 14:20:55 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
15/05/14 14:20:55 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
15/05/14 14:20:55 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
```

Does anyone have any idea what just happened?

Comment: Did you set an master ip in your VDQConsumer using `setMaster()` and not a valid master ip? Seems your Driver cannot talk to your master and stopped then.

Comment: does setMaster need to be used inside the app if it was set using the spark-submit argument?  Right now the app doesn't set the master at all, it relies on the host process to set the master